# Selecting a whole row data using variable selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have to questions:

- I have a list of almost 900 unique variables, but I wish to single out a list using a single row of data using an external cell, as shown below in the picture. I can not use the Filter option of excel, and hence therefore need a command in which excel can recognise an input from an external cell and recognise the row data. Previously I had used HLOOKUP() but since the order is not known therefore it did not work. I have also tried using IF statement to 'select a row', but it still did not work. Is there any other command, which I can use?
- Secondly, it is possible to pin point a number from a data set. For example is it possible in excel to ask it for data point which is (V1, C3). Hence using two criteria for both row and column to get a value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the whole row put this in B8:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$6,MATCH($A8,$A$1:$A$6,0),COLUMN(A1))
```

And copy over.

To get the specific Value use a second match in the third criterion:

```
=INDEX(B1:F6,MATCH(A8,A1:A6,0),MATCH("C3",B1:F1,0))
```

---

If one has the Dynamic Array formula `FILTER()` the first formula can be simplified to:

```
=FILTER(B1:F6,A8=A1:A6)
```

And Excel will fill across.

Comment: When getting the whole row, you need to lock the range columns absolute with **$** e.g. `=INDEX($B1:$F6,MATCH($A8,$A1:$A6,0),COLUMN(A1))` if you're going to copy over. Alternately, `=INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH($A8, $A1:$A$6, 0))`

Comment: Thank you very much!!